# What is this tool name and how can I select it?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

At this video at 16.50 He/she use some tools to move verticles like sculpt grab tool but I couldnt find that tool what is tool name how to select it can you help me?

https://youtu.be/DbGN7d6EiUA?t=1010

Comment: I think he has just activated the Proportional Editing option

Comment: he move verticle with circle is that so

Comment: if you enable Proportional Editing it will display a circle that will show you the influence radius of the option, you can change it with the mouse wheel I guess

Answer (score 1):

This is the proportional editing. You can enable it via its button at the top of the viewport:

[image: picture]

For more information, see [Blender Manual - Proportional Editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html)